# Is there any keyboard shortcut to the icons above the action bar in WoW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any keyboard shortcut to the icons above the action bar in WoW.

For example, is there a shortcut for activating the stealth mode for the rogue?

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl + 1 ? That works for pet classes at least.

Comment: Ok it was Ctrl + F1, but you lead me in the right direction. Make that an answer and you'll have it checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second level of action icons above the main action bar are all accessed with Ctrl + the function keys.  Unless you remap them, of course ;)